# Is WebView2 compatible with Angular?

Tags: angular, webview2

I have seen articles that suggest WebView2 is the Microsoft alternative to Electron.
But I can find nothing that affirms or denies that it's possible to use Angular with it.
So - can anyone suggest an approach that might make this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote a small angular service that can communicate with WebView2 using the approach documented in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/gettingstarted/wpf#step-7---communication-between-host-and-web-content

> - Web content in a WebView2 control may post a message to the host    using `window.chrome.webview.postMessage`. The host handles the message
>   using any registered `WebMessageReceived` on the host.
> - Hosts post messages to web content in a WebView2 control using    `CoreWebView2.PostWebMessageAsString` or
>   `CoreWebView2.PostWebMessageAsJSON`. The messages are caught by
>   handlers added to `window.chrome.webview.addEventListener`.

*web-view.service.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class WebViewService {

  public webViewMessage = new Subject<any>();

  constructor() {
    window?.chrome?.webview?.addEventListener('message', event => {
      this.webViewMessage.next(event.data);
    });
  }

  public postMessage(message: any) {
    window?.chrome?.webview?.postMessage(message);
  }
}

// add chrome to the Window context so typescript stops complaining
declare global {
  interface Window {
    chrome: any;
  }
}
```

Then subscribe to `webViewMessage` to receive messages or call `postMessage` to send.

**Option 2:** just use directly in your component:

```
window?.chrome?.webview?.addEventListener('message', event => {
      ...
    });
```

and

```
window?.chrome?.webview?.postMessage(message);
```